# Let $f:V'\rightarrow V$ be a linear function and $A$ be an affine subspace in V, then $f^{-1}(A)$ is an affine subspace in $V'$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, inverse-function

The fiber of a set is defined as: $f^{-1}(A) = \{x\in V' : f(x) \in A \}$ and the empty set is neither considered as a linear subspace nor an affine subspace.

---

Let $A=a+U$ with $a \in V$ and $U$ being a linear subspace of $V$.

I have already proven that $f^{-1}(U)$ is a linear subspace of $V'$, which I'm sure will come in handy.

I think the idea is that $a$ is being transformed to a new $a'$ whereas $U$ will be transformed to a new subspace $f^{-1}(U)$, but I can't fill in the gaps.

$
f^{-1}(A)=f^{-1}(a+U) \,\longrightarrow\, a'+f^{-1}(U)
$

Help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Do *your* references consider $\varnothing$ as an affine (sub)space? (definitions may vary, depending on the author)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f^{-1}(A)$ is non-empty, choose some $a'$ in it.
Then, $f(a')\in a+U$, or equivalently: $$a+U=f(a')+U.$$ Therefore,
$$x\in f^{-1}(A)\iff f(x)\in f(a')+U\iff f(x-a')\in U\iff x-a'\in f^{-1}(U),$$
so that
$$f^{-1}(A)=a'+f^{-1}(U).$$